# In v8 how do we extract "library" from useWeb3React()

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web3-react

This is the code in v6 of `"@web3-react/core"` package

```
const { chainId, library } = useWeb3ReactCore<Web3Provider>()
```

In v8 library doesn't exist, how can I get it?

I need to use following methods:

```
await library.getBlockNumber()
const result = await library.call({
  to: call.address,
  data: call.callData,
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: replacing `library` with `provider`

```
const { chainId, provider } = useWeb3ReactCore<Web3Provider>()
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced all `library` with `provider`, and it works for me.